# A version of the Portmanteau theorem - reference request

Tags: reference-request, limits-and-convergence, probability-distributions

I am trying to find peer-reviewed references to the following version of the Portmanteau theorem:
Let $M$ be a metric space and let $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of Borel probability measures. Then the following conditions are equivalent:

- $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $\mu$ with respect to the weak$^*$ topology,
- for every lower semicontinuous function $f\colon M\to\mathbb R$ bounded from below one has
  $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int f\text{d}\mu_n\geq \int f\text{d}\mu.$$

Comment: These days I'd expect to find it in books instead of articles.  Have you checked in Billingsley?

Comment: You're welcome; was it there?  If you find a satisfactory reference, you might like to post your own answer to this question.

Comment: The proof is about two lines, so if I were using this in a paper, I probably wouldn't bother with a reference - maybe just include a brief hint at the proof.  Forward: consider a sequence of bounded continuous functions increasing to $f$.  Reverse: what user111 said, or: if $f$ is bounded continuous, apply the second statement to $f$ and $-f$.

Comment: I know the proof, but I would prefer to cite it. I think the reference posted below by user111 is very good. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Portmanteau theorem does not seem to be stated in this form in Billingsley or other classical references that I checked. A possible reference for the direct implication is Theorem A.3.12. p.378 of

> Dupuis, P., Ellis, R.S., A weak convergence approach to the theory of
>   large deviations. Wiley Series in Probability and Statistics,
>   Wiley-Interscience, New York, 1997

The second statement implies that for an open set $O$ of $M$,
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\mu_n(O)\geq\mu(O),$$
so the reverse implication just follows from the above inequality since it is one of the equivalent properties to weak-* convergence, as stated in the usual version of the Portmanteau theorem.